# Скачивание apk с сайт

Tags: php, apk

Нужно реализовать скачивание apk с сайта.
Если его скачать apk через облако или телегу, устанавливается нормально.
Если указать ссылку на скачивание example.com/dowload/app.apk, скачивается zip.
Пробовал менять заголовки, скачивается apk, но при установке ошибка "не удалось обработать пакет"
Кто сталкивался, как решили проблему?

пример заголовков

```
$filename = 'app.apk';
```

header("Pragma: public", true);
header("Expires: 0"); // set expiration time
header("Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0"); header("Content-Type: application/force-download"); header("Content-Type: application/octet-stream"); header("Content-Type: application/download"); header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=".basename($filename)); header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary"); header("Content-Length: ".filesize($filename)); die(file_get_contents($filename));

Comment: пример заголовков:
        
    $filename = 'app.apk';
header("Pragma: public", true);
header("Expires: 0"); // set expiration time
header("Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0");
header("Content-Type: application/force-download");
header("Content-Type: application/octet-stream");
header("Content-Type: application/download");
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=".basename($filename));
header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary");
header("Content-Length: ".filesize($filename));
die(file_get_contents($filename));

Comment: 1) используйте [edit] а не комментарии для изменений. 2) вы на какой стороне выступаете, клиент или сервер, то есть отдаете файл, или запрашиваете его где-то?

Comment: я на стороне сервера, проблема отдать файл

Comment: Content-Type следует поменять на подходящий для apk `application/vnd.android.package-archive`, чтобы по сигнатуре zip не определялся

Comment: не важно application/octet-stream или application/vnd.android.package-archive, скачивается apk, но при установке ошибка "не удалось обработать пакет"